# Add URL parameters to a form

Tags: forms, url, parameters

I have this code form and I see is blocking from getting the url parameters, how can I unblock it to be shown under a custom field?

Code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stooners.od2.vtiger.com//layouts/v8/lib/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.min.css">
<form id="__vtigerWebForm_3" name="Website - Main Form LEADS" action="https://stooners.od2.vtiger.com/modules/Webforms/capture.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="publicid" value="42f14d9903792d1fd87d8cb36d619721">
    <input type="hidden" name="urlencodeenable" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Website - Main Form LEADS">
     <input type="hidden" name="__vtCurrency" value="1">
     <input type="hidden" data-type="storage" data-param="ca" name="country" value="">
     <input type="hidden" data-type="storage" data-param="web" name="leadsource" value="">
     <input type="hidden" data-type="storage" data-param="f1" name="cf_leads_form" value="">

<table><tbody>
<label>First Name*</label><input type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="40" data-label="" value="" required="">
<label>Last Name*</label><input type="text" name="lastname" maxlength="80" data-label="" value="" required="">
<label>Email*</label><input type="email" name="email" data-label="Primary Email" value="" required="">
<label>Phone*</label><input type="text" name="mobile" maxlength="50" data-label="" value="" required="" data-type="phone">
<label>Area of interest*</label><select name="industry" data-label="industry" required="">
    <option value="">Select Value</option>
            <option value="Art">
            Art
        </option>
            <option value="Business">
            Business
        </option>
            <option value="Healthcare">
            Healthcare
        </option>
            <option value="Technology">
            Technology
        </option>
            <option value="Other">
            Other
        </option>
    </select>

<label>Province*</label><select name="state" data-label="state" required="">
    <option value="">Select Value</option>
            <option value="Alberta">
            Alberta
        </option>
            <option value="British Columbia">
            British Columbia
        </option>
            <option value="Manitoba">
            Manitoba
        </option>
            <option value="New Brunswick">
            New Brunswick
        </option>
            <option value="Newfoundland and Labrador">
            Newfoundland and Labrador
        </option>
            <option value="Nova Scotia">
            Nova Scotia
        </option>
            <option value="Northwest Territories">
            Northwest Territories
        </option>
            <option value="Nunavut">
            Nunavut
        </option>
            <option value="Ontario">
            Ontario
        </option>
            <option value="Prince Edward Island">
            Prince Edward Island
        </option>
            <option value="Quebec">
            Quebec
        </option>
            <option value="Saskatchewan">
            Saskatchewan
        </option>
            <option value="Yukon">
            Yukon
        </option>
    </select>
</tbody></table>
            <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcmdSATAAAAAGWw734vGo0AXQwuxJS7RmDZA_Fe"></div>
        <input type="hidden" id="siteKey_3" value="6LcmdSATAAAAAGWw734vGo0AXQwuxJS7RmDZA_Fe">
                <script src="https://stooners.od2.vtiger.com//layouts/v8/lib/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script> <script src="https://stooners.od2.vtiger.com//layouts/v8/lib/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">window.addEventListener("load", function() {function getCountryCode() {var timezoneCountryMap = { "Africa/Abidjan": "ci", "Africa/Accra": "gh", "Africa/Addis_Ababa": "et", "Africa/Algiers": "dz", "Africa/Asmara": "er", "Africa/Asmera": "er", "Africa/Bamako": "ml", "Africa/Bangui": "cf", "Africa/Banjul": "gm", "Africa/Bissau": "gw", "Africa/Blantyre": "mw", "Africa/Brazzaville": "cg", "Africa/Bujumbura": "bi", "Africa/Cairo": "eg", "Africa/Casablanca": "ma", "Africa/Ceuta": "es", "Africa/Conakry": "gn", "Africa/Dakar": "sn", "Africa/Dar_es_Salaam": "tz", "Africa/Djibouti": "dj", "Africa/Douala": "cm", "Africa/El_Aaiun": "eh", "Africa/Freetown": "sl", "Africa/Gaborone": "bw", "Africa/Harare": "zw", "Africa/Johannesburg": "za", "Africa/Juba": "ss", "Africa/Kampala": "ug", "Africa/Khartoum": "sd", "Africa/Kigali": "rw", "Africa/Kinshasa": "cd", "Africa/Lagos": "ng", "Africa/Libreville": "ga", "Africa/Lome": "tg", "Africa/Luanda": "ao", "Africa/Lubumbashi": "cd", "Africa/Lusaka": "zm", "Africa/Malabo": "gq", "Africa/Maputo": "mz", "Africa/Maseru": "ls", "Africa/Mbabane": "sz", "Africa/Mogadishu": "so", "Africa/Monrovia": "lr", "Africa/Nairobi": "ke", "Africa/Ndjamena": "td", "Africa/Niamey": "ne", "Africa/Nouakchott": "mr", "Africa/Ouagadougou": "bf", "Africa/Porto-Novo": "bj", "Africa/Sao_Tome": "st", "Africa/Timbuktu": "ml", "Africa/Tripoli": "ly", "Africa/Tunis": "tn", "Africa/Windhoek": "na", "America/Adak": "us", "America/Anchorage": "us", "America/Anguilla": "ai", "America/Antigua": "ag", "America/Araguaina": "br", "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires": "ar", "America/Argentina/Catamarca": "ar", "America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia": "ar", "America/Argentina/Cordoba": "ar", "America/Argentina/Jujuy": "ar", "America/Argentina/La_Rioja": "ar", "America/Argentina/Mendoza": "ar", "America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos": "ar", "America/Argentina/Salta": "ar", "America/Argentina/San_Juan": "ar", "America/Argentina/San_Luis": "ar", "America/Argentina/Tucuman": "ar", "America/Argentina/Ushuaia": "ar", "America/Aruba": "aw", "America/Asuncion": "py", "America/Atikokan": "ca", "America/Atka": "us", "America/Bahia": "br", "America/Bahia_Banderas": "mx", "America/Barbados": "bb", "America/Belem": "br", "America/Belize": "bz", "America/Blanc-Sablon": "ca", "America/Boa_Vista": "br", "America/Bogota": "co", "America/Boise": "us", "America/Buenos_Aires": "ar", "America/Cambridge_Bay": "ca", "America/Campo_Grande": "br", "America/Cancun": "mx", "America/Caracas": "ve", "America/Catamarca": "ar", "America/Cayenne": "gf", "America/Cayman": "ky", "America/Chicago": "us", "America/Chihuahua": "mx", "America/Coral_Harbour": "ca", "America/Cordoba": "ar", "America/Costa_Rica": "cr", "America/Creston": "ca", "America/Cuiaba": "br", "America/Curacao": "cw", "America/Danmarkshavn": "gl", "America/Dawson": "ca", "America/Dawson_Creek": "ca", "America/Denver": "us", "America/Detroit": "us", "America/Dominica": "dm", "America/Edmonton": "ca", "America/Eirunepe": "br", "America/El_Salvador": "sv", "America/Ensenada": "mx", "America/Fort_Nelson": "ca", "America/Fort_Wayne": "us", "America/Fortaleza": "br", "America/Glace_Bay": "ca", "America/Godthab": "gl", "America/Goose_Bay": "ca", "America/Grand_Turk": "tc", "America/Grenada": "gd", "America/Guadeloupe": "gp", "America/Guatemala": "gt", "America/Guayaquil": "ec", "America/Guyana": "gy", "America/Halifax": "ca", "America/Havana": "cu", "America/Hermosillo": "mx", "America/Indiana/Indianapolis": "us", "America/Indiana/Knox": "us", "America/Indiana/Marengo": "us", "America/Indiana/Petersburg": "us", "America/Indiana/Tell_City": "us", "America/Indiana/Vevay": "us", "America/Indiana/Vincennes": "us", "America/Indiana/Winamac": "us", "America/Indianapolis": "us", "America/Inuvik": "ca", "America/Iqaluit": "ca", "America/Jamaica": "jm", "America/Jujuy": "ar", "America/Juneau": "us", "America/Kentucky/Louisville": "us", "America/Kentucky/Monticello": "us", "America/Knox_IN": "us", "America/Kralendijk": "bq", "America/La_Paz": "bo", "America/Lima": "pe", "America/Los_Angeles": "us", "America/Louisville": "us", "America/Lower_Princes": "sx", "America/Maceio": "br", "America/Managua": "ni", "America/Manaus": "br", "America/Marigot": "mf", "America/Martinique": "mq", "America/Matamoros": "mx", "America/Mazatlan": "mx", "America/Mendoza": "ar", "America/Menominee": "us", "America/Merida": "mx", "America/Metlakatla": "us", "America/Mexico_City": "mx", "America/Miquelon": "pm", "America/Moncton": "ca", "America/Monterrey": "mx", "America/Montevideo": "uy", "America/Montreal": "ca", "America/Montserrat": "ms", "America/Nassau": "bs", "America/New_York": "us", "America/Nipigon": "ca", "America/Nome": "us", "America/Noronha": "br", "America/North_Dakota/Beulah": "us", "America/North_Dakota/Center": "us", "America/North_Dakota/New_Salem": "us", "America/Nuuk": "gl", "America/Ojinaga": "mx", "America/Panama": "pa", "America/Pangnirtung": "ca", "America/Paramaribo": "sr", "America/Phoenix": "us", "America/Port-au-Prince": "ht", "America/Port_of_Spain": "tt", "America/Porto_Acre": "br", "America/Porto_Velho": "br", "America/Puerto_Rico": "pr", "America/Punta_Arenas": "cl", "America/Rainy_River": "ca", "America/Rankin_Inlet": "ca", "America/Recife": "br", "America/Regina": "ca", "America/Resolute": "ca", "America/Rio_Branco": "br", "America/Rosario": "ar", "America/Santa_Isabel": "mx", "America/Santarem": "br", "America/Santiago": "cl", "America/Santo_Domingo": "do", "America/Sao_Paulo": "br", "America/Scoresbysund": "gl", "America/Shiprock": "us", "America/Sitka": "us", "America/St_Barthelemy": "bl", "America/St_Johns": "ca", "America/St_Kitts": "kn", "America/St_Lucia": "lc", "America/St_Thomas": "vi", "America/St_Vincent": "vc", "America/Swift_Current": "ca", "America/Tegucigalpa": "hn", "America/Thule": "gl", "America/Thunder_Bay": "ca", "America/Tijuana": "mx", "America/Toronto": "ca", "America/Tortola": "vg", "America/Vancouver": "ca", "America/Virgin": "vi", "America/Whitehorse": "ca", "America/Winnipeg": "ca", "America/Yakutat": "us", "America/Yellowknife": "ca", "Antarctica/Casey": "aq", "Antarctica/Davis": "aq", "Antarctica/DumontDUrville": "aq", "Antarctica/Macquarie": "au", "Antarctica/Mawson": "aq", "Antarctica/McMurdo": "aq", "Antarctica/Palmer": "aq", "Antarctica/Rothera": "aq", "Antarctica/South_Pole": "aq", "Antarctica/Syowa": "aq", "Antarctica/Troll": "aq", "Antarctica/Vostok": "aq", "Arctic/Longyearbyen": "sj", "Asia/Aden": "ye", "Asia/Almaty": "kz", "Asia/Amman": "jo", "Asia/Anadyr": "ru", "Asia/Aqtau": "kz", "Asia/Aqtobe": "kz", "Asia/Ashgabat": "tm", "Asia/Ashkhabad": "tm", "Asia/Atyrau": "kz", "Asia/Baghdad": "iq", "Asia/Bahrain": "bh", "Asia/Baku": "az", "Asia/Bangkok": "th", "Asia/Barnaul": "ru", "Asia/Beirut": "lb", "Asia/Bishkek": "kg", "Asia/Brunei": "bn", "Asia/Calcutta": "in", "Asia/Chita": "ru", "Asia/Choibalsan": "mn", "Asia/Chongqing": "cn", "Asia/Chungking": "cn", "Asia/Colombo": "lk", "Asia/Dacca": "bd", "Asia/Damascus": "sy", "Asia/Dhaka": "bd", "Asia/Dili": "tl", "Asia/Dubai": "ae", "Asia/Dushanbe": "tj", "Asia/Famagusta": "cy", "Asia/Gaza": "ps", "Asia/Harbin": "cn", "Asia/Hebron": "ps", "Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh": "vn", "Asia/Hong_Kong": "hk", "Asia/Hovd": "mn", "Asia/Irkutsk": "ru", "Asia/Istanbul": "tr", "Asia/Jakarta": "id", "Asia/Jayapura": "id", "Asia/Jerusalem": "il", "Asia/Kabul": "af", "Asia/Kamchatka": "ru", "Asia/Karachi": "pk", "Asia/Kashgar": "cn", "Asia/Kathmandu": "np", "Asia/Katmandu": "np", "Asia/Khandyga": "ru", "Asia/Kolkata": "in", "Asia/Krasnoyarsk": "ru", "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur": "my", "Asia/Kuching": "my", "Asia/Kuwait": "kw", "Asia/Macao": "mo", "Asia/Macau": "mo", "Asia/Magadan": "ru", "Asia/Makassar": "id", "Asia/Manila": "ph", "Asia/Muscat": "om", "Asia/Nicosia": "cy", "Asia/Novokuznetsk": "ru", "Asia/Novosibirsk": "ru", "Asia/Omsk": "ru", "Asia/Oral": "kz", "Asia/Phnom_Penh": "kh", "Asia/Pontianak": "id", "Asia/Pyongyang": "kp", "Asia/Qatar": "qa", "Asia/Qostanay": "kz", "Asia/Qyzylorda": "kz", "Asia/Rangoon": "mm", "Asia/Riyadh": "sa", "Asia/Saigon": "vn", "Asia/Sakhalin": "ru", "Asia/Samarkand": "uz", "Asia/Seoul": "kr", "Asia/Shanghai": "cn", "Asia/Singapore": "sg", "Asia/Srednekolymsk": "ru", "Asia/Taipei": "tw", "Asia/Tashkent": "uz", "Asia/Tbilisi": "ge", "Asia/Tehran": "ir", "Asia/Tel_Aviv": "il", "Asia/Thimbu": "bt", "Asia/Thimphu": "bt", "Asia/Tokyo": "jp", "Asia/Tomsk": "ru", "Asia/Ujung_Pandang": "id", "Asia/Ulaanbaatar": "mn", "Asia/Ulan_Bator": "mn", "Asia/Urumqi": "cn", "Asia/Ust-Nera": "ru", "Asia/Vientiane": "la", "Asia/Vladivostok": "ru", "Asia/Yakutsk": "ru", "Asia/Yangon": "mm", "Asia/Yekaterinburg": "ru", "Asia/Yerevan": "am", "Atlantic/Azores": "pt", "Atlantic/Bermuda": "bm", "Atlantic/Canary": "es", "Atlantic/Cape_Verde": "cv", "Atlantic/Faeroe": "fo", "Atlantic/Faroe": "fo", "Atlantic/Jan_Mayen": "sj", "Atlantic/Madeira": "pt", "Atlantic/Reykjavik": "is", "Atlantic/South_Georgia": "gs", "Atlantic/St_Helena": "sh", "Atlantic/Stanley": "fk", "Australia/ACT": "au", "Australia/Adelaide": "au", "Australia/Brisbane": "au", "Australia/Broken_Hill": "au", "Australia/Canberra": "au", "Australia/Currie": "au", "Australia/Darwin": "au", "Australia/Eucla": "au", "Australia/Hobart": "au", "Australia/LHI": "au", "Australia/Lindeman": "au", "Australia/Lord_Howe": "au", "Australia/Melbourne": "au", "Australia/North": "au", "Australia/NSW": "au", "Australia/Perth": "au", "Australia/Queensland": "au", "Australia/South": "au", "Australia/Sydney": "au", "Australia/Tasmania": "au", "Australia/Victoria": "au", "Australia/West": "au", "Australia/Yancowinna": "au", "Brazil/Acre": "br", "Brazil/DeNoronha": "br", "Brazil/East": "br", "Brazil/West": "br", "Canada/Atlantic": "ca", "Canada/Central": "ca", "Canada/Eastern": "ca", "Canada/Mountain": "ca", "Canada/Newfoundland": "ca", "Canada/Pacific": "ca", "Canada/Saskatchewan": "ca", "Canada/Yukon": "ca", "Chile/Continental": "cl", "Chile/EasterIsland": "cl", "Cuba": "cu", "Egypt": "eg", "Eire": "ie", "Europe/Amsterdam": "nl", "Europe/Andorra": "ad", "Europe/Astrakhan": "ru", "Europe/Athens": "gr", "Europe/Belfast": "gb", "Europe/Belgrade": "rs", "Europe/Berlin": "de", "Europe/Bratislava": "sk", "Europe/Brussels": "be", "Europe/Bucharest": "ro", "Europe/Budapest": "hu", "Europe/Busingen": "de", "Europe/Chisinau": "md", "Europe/Copenhagen": "dk", "Europe/Dublin": "ie", "Europe/Gibraltar": "gi", "Europe/Guernsey": "gg", "Europe/Helsinki": "fi", "Europe/Isle_of_Man": "im", "Europe/Istanbul": "tr", "Europe/Jersey": "je", "Europe/Kaliningrad": "ru", "Europe/Kiev": "ua", "Europe/Kirov": "ru", "Europe/Lisbon": "pt", "Europe/Ljubljana": "si", "Europe/London": "gb", "Europe/Luxembourg": "lu", "Europe/Madrid": "es", "Europe/Malta": "mt", "Europe/Mariehamn": "ax", "Europe/Minsk": "by", "Europe/Monaco": "mc", "Europe/Moscow": "ru", "Europe/Nicosia": "cy", "Europe/Oslo": "no", "Europe/Paris": "fr", "Europe/Podgorica": "me", "Europe/Prague": "cz", "Europe/Riga": "lv", "Europe/Rome": "it", "Europe/Samara": "ru", "Europe/San_Marino": "sm", "Europe/Sarajevo": "ba", "Europe/Saratov": "ru", "Europe/Simferopol": "ru", "Europe/Skopje": "mk", "Europe/Sofia": "bg", "Europe/Stockholm": "se", "Europe/Tallinn": "ee", "Europe/Tirane": "al", "Europe/Tiraspol": "md", "Europe/Ulyanovsk": "ru", "Europe/Uzhgorod": "ua", "Europe/Vaduz": "li", "Europe/Vatican": "va", "Europe/Vienna": "at", "Europe/Vilnius": "lt", "Europe/Volgograd": "ru", "Europe/Warsaw": "pl", "Europe/Zagreb": "hr", "Europe/Zaporozhye": "ua", "Europe/Zurich": "ch", "GB": "gb", "GB-Eire": "gb", "Hongkong": "hk", "Iceland": "is", "Indian/Antananarivo": "mg", "Indian/Chagos": "io", "Indian/Christmas": "cx", "Indian/Cocos": "cc", "Indian/Comoro": "km", "Indian/Kerguelen": "tf", "Indian/Mahe": "sc", "Indian/Maldives": "mv", "Indian/Mauritius": "mu", "Indian/Mayotte": "yt", "Indian/Reunion": "re", "Iran": "ir", "Israel": "il", "Jamaica": "jm", "Japan": "jp", "Kwajalein": "mh", "Libya": "ly", "Mexico/BajaNorte": "mx", "Mexico/BajaSur": "mx", "Mexico/General": "mx", "Navajo": "us", "NZ": "nz", "NZ-CHAT": "nz", "Pacific/Apia": "ws", "Pacific/Auckland": "nz", "Pacific/Bougainville": "pg", "Pacific/Chatham": "nz", "Pacific/Chuuk": "fm", "Pacific/Easter": "cl", "Pacific/Efate": "vu", "Pacific/Enderbury": "ki", "Pacific/Fakaofo": "tk", "Pacific/Fiji": "fj", "Pacific/Funafuti": "tv", "Pacific/Galapagos": "ec", "Pacific/Gambier": "pf", "Pacific/Guadalcanal": "sb", "Pacific/Guam": "gu", "Pacific/Honolulu": "us", "Pacific/Johnston": "um", "Pacific/Kanton": "ki", "Pacific/Kiritimati": "ki", "Pacific/Kosrae": "fm", "Pacific/Kwajalein": "mh", "Pacific/Majuro": "mh", "Pacific/Marquesas": "pf", "Pacific/Midway": "um", "Pacific/Nauru": "nr", "Pacific/Niue": "nu", "Pacific/Norfolk": "nf", "Pacific/Noumea": "nc", "Pacific/Pago_Pago": "as", "Pacific/Palau": "pw", "Pacific/Pitcairn": "pn", "Pacific/Pohnpei": "fm", "Pacific/Ponape": "fm", "Pacific/Port_Moresby": "pg", "Pacific/Rarotonga": "ck", "Pacific/Saipan": "mp", "Pacific/Samoa": "ws", "Pacific/Tahiti": "pf", "Pacific/Tarawa": "ki", "Pacific/Tongatapu": "to", "Pacific/Truk": "fm", "Pacific/Wake": "um", "Pacific/Wallis": "wf", "Pacific/Yap": "fm", "Poland": "pl", "Portugal": "pt", "PRC": "cn", "ROC": "tw", "ROK": "kr", "Singapore": "sg", "Turkey": "tr", "US/Alaska": "us", "US/Aleutian": "us", "US/Arizona": "us", "US/Central": "us", "US/East-Indiana": "us", "US/Eastern": "us", "US/Hawaii": "us", "US/Indiana-Starke": "us", "US/Michigan": "us", "US/Mountain": "us", "US/Pacific": "us", "US/Samoa": "ws", "W-SU": "ru" };var timezone = "";var country = "us";if(Intl && Intl.DateTimeFormat) timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;if (timezoneCountryMap[timezone]) {country = timezoneCountryMap[timezone];}return country;}var phoneFields = document.querySelectorAll('[data-type="phone"]');if (phoneFields && phoneFields.length) {phoneFields.forEach(function(ele) { window.intlTelInput(ele, {initialCountry: "auto",separateDialCode: true,autoPlaceholder: false,hiddenInput: ele.getAttribute("name"),geoIpLookup: function (success, failure) {success(getCountryCode())},});});}});</script>
        <input type="hidden" id="phoneLibScript_3" value="https://stooners.od2.vtiger.com//layouts/v8/lib/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.min.js" disabled="">
        <input type="hidden" id="phoneUtilScript_3" value="https://stooners.od2.vtiger.com//layouts/v8/lib/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js" disabled="">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="vtigerFormSubmitBtn_3">
</form>
                <script  type="text/javascript">window.addEventListener("load", function() { var N=navigator.appName, ua=navigator.userAgent, tem;var M=ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);if(M && (tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];M=M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion, "-?"];var browserName = M[0];var form = document.getElementById("__vtigerWebForm_3"), inputs = form.elements; form.onsubmit = function(event) { document.getElementById("vtigerFormSubmitBtn_3").disabled=true;var required = [], att, val; var startDate;var endDate;var endDate1;for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { att = inputs[i].getAttribute("required"); val = inputs[i].value; type = inputs[i].type; if(inputs[i].name == "birthday"){birthdayDate = new Date(inputs[i].value);todayDate = new Date();todayDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);birthdayDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);if(birthdayDate >= todayDate){alert("Date of Birth should be less than Today's Date.");document.getElementById("vtigerFormSubmitBtn_3").disabled=false;return false;}}if(inputs[i].getAttribute("data-type") == "anniversary" && inputs[i].value){anniversaryDate = new Date(inputs[i].value);todayDate = new Date();todayDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);anniversaryDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);if(anniversaryDate >= todayDate){var anniversaryLabel = inputs[i].getAttribute("data-displaylabel");alert(anniversaryLabel+" should be less than Today's Date.");document.getElementById("vtigerFormSubmitBtn_3").disabled=false;return false;}}if(inputs[i].name=="support_start_date" || inputs[i].name=="startdate"){startDate = inputs[i].value;}if(inputs[i].name=="support_end_date" || inputs[i].name=="targetenddate" || inputs[i].name=="enddate"){endDate = inputs[i].value;}if(inputs[i].name=="actualenddate"){endDate1 = inputs[i].value;}if(type == "email") {if(val != "") {var elemLabel = inputs[i].getAttribute("data-label");var emailFilter = /^[_/a-zA-Z0-9]+([!"#$%&()*+,./:;<=>?\^_`{|}~-]?[a-zA-Z0-9/_/-])*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\_\-\.]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.([\-\_]?[a-zA-Z0-9])+(\.?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$/;var illegalChars= /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\"\[\]]/ ;if (!emailFilter.test(val)) {alert("For "+ elemLabel +" field please enter valid email address"); document.getElementById("vtigerFormSubmitBtn_3").disabled=false; return false;} else if (val.match(illegalChars)) {alert(elemLabel +" field contains illegal characters"); document.getElementById("vtigerFormSubmitBtn_3").disabled=false; return false;}}}if(startDate){if(typeof startDate !== "undefined") {if(endDate){if(typeof endDate !== "undefined") {startDate = new Date(startDate);endDate = new Date(endDate);if(endDate < startDate){alert("End Date should be greater than or equal to Start Date");document.getElementById("vtigerFormSubmitBtn_3").disabled = false;return false;}}}if(endDate1){if(typeof endDate1 !== "undefined") {startDate = new Date(startDate);endDate1 = new Date(endDate1);if(endDate1 < startDate){alert("End Date should be greater than or equal to Start Date");document.getElementById("vtigerFormSubmitBtn_3").disabled = false;return false;}}}}}if (att != null) { if (val.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "") == "") { required.push(inputs[i].getAttribute("label")); } } } if (required.length > 0) { alert("The following fields are required: " + required.join()); document.getElementById("vtigerFormSubmitBtn_3").disabled=false;return false; } var numberTypeInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=number]");for (var i = 0; i < numberTypeInputs.length; i++) { val = numberTypeInputs[i].value;var elemLabel = numberTypeInputs[i].getAttribute("label");var elemDataType = numberTypeInputs[i].getAttribute("datatype");if(val != "") {if(elemDataType == "double") {var numRegex = /^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/;}else{var numRegex = /^[+-]?\d+$/;}if (!numRegex.test(val)) {alert("For "+ elemLabel +" field please enter valid number"); document.getElementById("vtigerFormSubmitBtn_3").disabled=false; return false;}}}var dateTypeInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=date]");for (var i = 0; i < dateTypeInputs.length; i++) {dateVal = dateTypeInputs[i].value;var elemLabel = dateTypeInputs[i].getAttribute("label");if(dateVal != "") {var dateRegex = /^[1-9][0-9]{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9]{1})-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]|[1-9]{1})$/;if(!dateRegex.test(dateVal)) {alert("For "+ elemLabel +" field please enter valid date in required format"); document.getElementById("vtigerFormSubmitBtn_3").disabled=false; return false;}}}var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input");var totalFileSize = 0;for(var i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i++) {if(inputElems[i].type.toLowerCase() === "file") {var file = inputElems[i].files[0];if(typeof file !== "undefined") {var totalFileSize = totalFileSize + file.size;}}}if(totalFileSize > 52428800) {alert("Maximum allowed file size including all files is 50MB.");document.getElementById("vtigerFormSubmitBtn_3").disabled=false;return false;}var inputElem = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=file]");var fileSize = 0;for(var i = 0; i < inputElem.length; i++) {if(inputElem[i].type.toLowerCase() ===  "file") {if(inputElem[i].hasAttribute("selectedTypeImage")) {var imageFile = inputElem[i].files[0];var fileSize = imageFile.size;}}if(fileSize > 5242880) {alert("Maximum allowed image size is 5MB.");document.getElementById("vtigerFormSubmitBtn_3").disabled=false;return false;}}document.getElementById("vtigerFormSubmitBtn_3").disabled = true;var recaptchaResponse = form.getElementsByClassName("g-recaptcha-response")[0].value;if (recaptchaResponse) {var currentUrl = window.location.href;var urlHash = window.location.hash;currentUrl = currentUrl.replace(urlHash, "");currentUrl = currentUrl.replace("#", "");currentUrl = currentUrl.split("?");currentUrl = currentUrl[0];var currentUrlTag = document.createElement("input");currentUrlTag.type = "hidden";currentUrlTag.name = "current_url";currentUrlTag.value = currentUrl;document.getElementById("__vtigerWebForm_3").appendChild(currentUrlTag);return true;} else {alert("Captcha not verified. Please verify captcha.");document.getElementById("vtigerFormSubmitBtn_3").disabled = false;return false;}};var getParams=function(a){var e={},t=document.createElement('a');t.href=a;for(var r=t.search.substring(1).split('&'),l=0;l<r.length;l++){var o=r[l].split('=');if(o[0]){var c=decodeURIComponent(o[1]);c&&(e[o[0]]=c,c&&localStorage.setItem(o[0],c))}}return e};document.querySelectorAll('[data-type=storage]').forEach(a=>{if(a){var e=a.getAttribute('data-param'),t=localStorage.getItem(e);t&&(a.value=t)}});var allParameters=getParams(window.location.href);Object.keys(allParameters).length>0&&document.querySelectorAll('[data-type=url]').forEach(a=>{if(a){var e=a.getAttribute('data-param');allParameters[e]&&(a.value=allParameters[e])}});});</script>
```

I try to change this lines but no results

```
<input type="hidden" name="urlencodeenable" value="1">
```

and the last section goes into url details, what should I need to be pointing to?

{var currentUrl = window.location.href;var urlHash = window.location.hash;currentUrl = currentUrl.replace(urlHash, "");currentUrl = currentUrl.replace("#", "");currentUrl = currentUrl.split("?");currentUrl = currentUrl[0];var currentUrlTag = document.createElement("input");currentUrlTag.type = "hidden";currentUrlTag.name = "current_url";currentUrlTag.value = currentUrl;document.getElementById("__vtigerWebForm_3").appendChild(currentUrlTag);return true;} else {alert("Captcha not verified. Please verify captcha.");document.getElementById("vtigerFormSubmitBtn_3").disabled = false;return false;}};var getParams=function(a){var e={},t=document.createElement('a');t.href=a;for(var r=t.search.substring(1).split('&'),l=0;l<r.length;l++){var o=r[l].split('=');if(o[0]){var c=decodeURIComponent(o[1]);c&&(e[o[0]]=c,c&&localStorage.setItem(o[0],c))}}return e};document.querySelectorAll('[data-type=storage]').forEach(a=>{if(a){var e=a.getAttribute('data-param'),t=localStorage.getItem(e);t&&(a.value=t)}});var allParameters=getParams(window.location.href);Object.keys(allParameters).length>0&&document.querySelectorAll('[data-type=url]').forEach(a=>{if(a){var e=a.getAttribute('data-param');allParameters[e]&&(a.value=allParameters[e])}});});